# Subtype of Record<string, X> without the index signature

Tags: typescript

I want to constrain a type parameter `T` to have **only** `string` keys with values of type say `number`. So valid subtypes would be the following:

```js
type Yes_1 = { a: 1, b: 2 }

interface Yes_2 { a: number; b: number }
```

And these wouldn't be valid subtypes:

```js
type No_1 = { a: number, b: string }
```

I would like to be able to do the following:

```js
function F<X extends Record<string, number>>() {}
```

And it seems to work if I do:

```js
F<Yes_1>()
```

But `Yes_2` doesn't work because it says:

```js
F<Yes_2>()
// TS2344: Type  Yes_2  does not satisfy the constraint  Record<string, number> 
/// Index signature for type  string  is missing in type  Yes_2
```

But I don't want the type to have an index signature! What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on `X` to be recursive.  Instead of `Record<string, number>` which has an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) and therefore rejects any [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) without one (see [microsoft/TypeScript#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300)), you can use `Record<keyof X, number>`, which cares specifically only about the keys present in `X`:

```
function F<X extends Record<keyof X, number>>() { }

F<Yes_1>() // okay
F<Yes_2>() // okay
F<No_1>(); // error
```

I'm not sure if you need to prohibit non-`string` keys, but if so, you can write your own [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) that has that effect by having [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) properties depending on the type of the key:

```
function F<X extends
  { [K in keyof X]: K extends string ? number : never }
>() { }
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#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)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function accepting a type extending `Yes_2` it would accept object like this

```js
declare function acceptingYes2<T extends Yes_2>(yes2: T): void
acceptingYes2({a: 3, b: 4, c: 'this is to be expected'})
```

so you need to restrain the `interface Yes_2` like this

```
interface Yes_2 extends Record<string, number> { a: number; b: number }
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAmhDOB9AjFAvFA3lAhgLimQBooAjAgJigF8AoWgSwDtgIAnAMxwGNo4kq2fFCYBXALal2AbjIExk9jVoB6FVACCTACZRgACwTQA7gHtRAG21MA5MDLQAbjgsNd8UaVCR4ees1ZOHj4ERABmKAgAD1YdeCgAJQhuUzZtAB54YDZmAHMSBSk2AD4sXHkJItlyEUqlOlpvaAA5UxR0MuFC9hIarJymXOU1KABJKDNLXVcAa2hgUwdcUgt5xe1Fg2gOUwsLU2M8v1oOUSZuYAZTJigAMXSADUiYiDjE5NSM-ryCupLigAUAEosHQRlpdAx7PAIBBxPEFhNUjMoAwOGMoBtjvd+ChAUDVOoAEKiey4qgbBC2exmNgoqTcHCiGGo6E4EC+eg40IUfGEqAAFQAyhQwgAWMUEAXgaCwHlQTGmBAiUxsy7wDggPSGKApJj9HABBVJFJpTLZH61RQlKCE9SjHTRKDwBi5Jg4YCiNjbVJ6GUK76DBUMeLiEMuoPMP2QBXk220bTJCw4b1QU7nS7XXDcXhgS6DfgUdIC56xbTxcmAkAIChSoEERymNy0Hi5-O5QsAzDCMK9AhikjcAh2fQh1EIxZSZ6QC4QbQ2agE2jcpBhfFAA)

---

```js
interface Maybe_2 extends Yes_2 {
  info: "Interface extending Yes_2 could have additional properties of different subtypes as long as the Yes_2 doesn't restrict them"
}
```

you can also restrict the additional properties like this:

```js
interface Yes_2 { a: number; b: number; [key: string]: number }
```

or

```js
interface Yes_2 { a: number; b: number; [key: string]: never }
```