# typescript how do i infer from mapping type

Tags: typescript, type-inference, mapped-types

Hi I create a plugin and a function to callPlugin action.

```js
export class Plugin {
    actions = {
        'join': ({ groupId }: { groupId: string }) => {

        },
        'addPoint': ({ point }: { point: number }) => {

        }
    }
}


export type PluginParams<T> = T extends {
    actions: Record<infer X, (param: infer Params) => any>
} ? {
    action: X,
    data: Params, // how do i do mapping type  ?
} : never;

function callPlugin<T>(v: PluginParams<T>) {
    console.log(v);
}


callPlugin<Plugin>({
    action: 'addPoint',
    data: {
        // it has an error here how do i fix that 
        // when action is `addPoint` it should only require point.
        point: 100
    }
})
```

I can infer the params from the plugin, but I don't know how to use them with the mapping type. I simply want it to map action name with the parameters from the action function

I already check all similar question on stackoverflow but i can't still find a solution.

Thank you.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKApgHgDg9gTgFwAQGMA2BDAzlpAFNAVwHMBLAOyQG9Qk6kMUFSZzcBea2+ngcgCsYFXgC4kACipJicGISgBJACZIAvmKky5ipWKwI4FYmoCUSdgD4uIbjzqqANLbu8MSpXiHkEoiVNgUyOrUSAHeYuSEALYARmBwpuZWNDYgdvSqzpkg2aCgkLCISAgAnlBg+ERk5HgYcBhRWAA8ACpWnC1IkAhg5Eq4KTyMzKxYYgBKYCjwSk0UAGbxSAAaDhJQdQ1iC0u19Y1mlgzkJRagqkgA-NZDTCzkYqvOShgIGGJ7DVhrAPQ-SAALGAAdyQShgSFIYIhUQwUCgRmKZQqV3OSAiYAAbvEANx5EDzQjkO6sVAYNBoAgkCitCziTEfKoUT6NWlmQb0aZsGBoMAAOjQMGI9JMeJy+NAKHJlKZ5CaVOqdI5dGG9zErncnkCvCcaXoLzeGjof0BIOhkKQ81IEGKANedGBAN6DBJlFIuAABm4PF4EB7IchgaQKUg4GAAI6EUhh0K+44qF0jN2ewQUf0GjBIIMhsOR6MVLTyZRIZw8MIIMQARgADNWsucTPiTS07eQANZIEpyUBAA)

Comment: Are you planning to actually manually specify the type argument as shown in `callPlugin<Plugin>(...)`?  If so then there is no inference involved and you just want `PluginParams<T>` to be a union of all possible input types, possibly like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mZyrJN) shows.  Is that what you're looking for? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes your solution is what i want. thank you again you help me too many times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're going to manually specify the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type argument when you call `callPlugin()`, like `callPlugin<Plugin>({⋯})`, then there you want to define `PluginParams<T>` so that `PluginParams<Plugin>` becomes a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) of the acceptable inputs of the form:

```
type Demo = PluginParams<Plugin>
/* type Demo = {
    action: "join";
    data: {
        groupId: string;
    };
} | {
    action: "addPoint";
    data: {
        point: number;
    };
} */
```

Here's one way to do that:

```
type PluginParams<T extends {
    actions: Record<keyof T["actions"], (p: any) => any>
}> = { [K in keyof T["actions"]]:
    { action: K, data: T["actions"][K] extends (p: infer P) => any ? P : never }
}[keyof T["actions"]]
```

I'm [constraining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T` so that it has an `actions` property of type `Record<keyof T["actions"], (p: any) => any>`, so that it only accepts things suitably `Plugin`-like.  Note that instead of the recursive `keyof T["actions"]` you could probably use `string`, but sometimes that doesn't play nicely with interface types (see [Subtype of Record<string, X> without the index signature](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77222138/2887218)).

Then all we do is [map](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over the properties of `T["actions"]` and transform them to object with an `action` and `data` property of the appropriate type, and subsequently [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) it with the union of keys to get a union out.  This sort of indexed-mapped-type of the form `{[P in K]: F<P>}[K]` so that a union in `K` (e.g., `K1 | K2 | K3`) produces a union in the output (e.g., `F<K1> | F<K2> | F<K3>`) is called a "distributive object type" and is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).

You can verify that `PluginParams<Plugin>` becomes the desired discriminated union, and that your call works as desired if you define `callPlugin` to accept `PluginParams<T>`:

```
function callPlugin<T extends {
    actions: Record<keyof T["actions"], (p: any) => any>
}>(v: PluginParams<T>) {
    console.log(v);
}

callPlugin<Plugin>({
    action: 'addPoint',
    data: {
        point: 100
    }
})

callPlugin<Plugin>({
    action: 'join',
    data: {
        point: 100 // error! 
        // Type '{ point: number; }' is not 
        // assignable to type '{ groupId: string; }'.
    }
})

callPlugin<Plugin>({
    action: 'join',
    data: {
        point: 100 // error! 
        // Type '{ point: number; }' is not 
        // assignable to type '{ groupId: string; }'.
    }
})
```

---

Do note that this is a somewhat nonstandard way of writing and calling generic functions.  It requires that the caller manually specify the type argument, which is usually inferred.  I'd expect that either your `callPlugin()` function should also take a `plugin` argument from which `T` can be inferred, or you should refactor so that all the generic stuff is dispensed with before anyone calls `callPlugin()`, so that nobody has to remember to specify the type argument manually.  This is technically out of scope for the question as asked, so I won't delve further into this, other than to say to be careful that your code can be properly consumed by callers.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-mVap1eoWMwqujDNgwNBgAB0aBgxFbJlt8bTGY75GFpQoFkkzjVSFcHqDvCc1ro+r9A7sYWDSAAjAAGa9ZM4mefpzOr5dL9enrcCLz7n0GgtnkGYg3teSAShKTRwLIcAAIRIEa9DgXMrLbv4QFIJEsTxNqai8HcuDkDAyAIXQSHYFgpDEOQGAxKOsrcnKxS8JosimroSD6IY5DEDhqi8GO945I+IBAA)